# Is there a way to repeat the code, with different variables without having to repeat the code by hand?

Tags: c#

I am trying to use C# to do math, and in this case I need to repeat a string of code multiple times and then sum the results, the only thing that changes is one number that goes from 2 to 10. (I am aware python might be a better language to do math)

A thought that I had was doing a while loop, but I don't know how to use the while loop to do what I want.

```cs
static void Main()
{
    double r = 5;
    double n = 12;
    double fact = 1;
    double foct = 1;
    double fuct = 1;
    double p = 0.85;
    {
        for (double x = 1; x <= n; x++)
        {
            fact *= x;
        }
        for (double y = 1; y <= r; y++)
        {
            foct *= y;
        }
        for (double z = 1; z <= n - r; z++)
        {
            fuct *= z;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine((fact / (foct * fuct) * Math.Pow(p, r) * Math.Pow(1 - p, n - r)));
}
```

More specifically, I need to make the `r` go from 2 to 10, and then sum up each result after, which I could do by just repeating the code and summing everything up, but I wonder if there is a way of automating it.

I am new to coding as you may be able to tell, so things might not be so obvious to me.

Comment: You could employ a `for` loop that wraps your entire function, and have the values incremented by some factor of the current index.

Comment: every repeated thing in code, should be a **function**.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because code review questions should be posted on the Code Review stack exchange site.

Comment: @DanielMann please don't use the existence of the Code Review site as a reason to close a question. Evaluate the request and use a reason like *Needs more focus*, *primarily opinion-based*, etc. Then you can mention to the OP that it can be posted on Code Review if it is [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please see [_Does being on-topic at another Stack Exchange site automatically make a question off-topic for Stack Overflow?_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287400/1575353).

Comment: oh, my bad, I didn't know there was another website to ask for these kinds of questions, I will try to remember to use that site next time I have a similar question, apologies!

Comment: since just one single answer pointed at your code and recognized it as **factorials**, I think I better repeat that here. you're writing code for **factorials**, and for **binomial coefficients**, and that is supposed to be a **function**. either C# already has it, or you have to write it. -- you clearly know how to use loops, so the suggestion to wrap everything in a loop might not address what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps wrapping your function in a `for` loop would work. You could then use the index of the loop to set your `r` value:

```cs
for (int i = 2; i < 11; i++)
{
    double r = i;
    double n = 12;
    double fact = 1;
    double foct = 1;
    double fuct = 1;
    double p = 0.85;

    for (double x = 1; x <= n; x++)
    {
        fact *= x;
    }
    for (double y = 1; y <= r; y++)
    {
        foct *= y;
    }
    for (double z = 1; z <= n - r; z++)
    {
        fuct *= z;
    }

    Console.WriteLine((fact / (foct * fuct) * Math.Pow(p, r) * Math.Pow(1 - p, n - r)));
}
```

If you wanted to use those values inside of the `for` loop to create a sum, you would then need to employ the same tactics you were using with your other `for` loops -- declare the variables outside of the loop:

```
double sum = 0;

for (int i = 2; i < 11; i++)
{
    double r = i;
    double n = 12;
    double fact = 1;
    double foct = 1;
    double fuct = 1;
    double p = 0.85;

    for (double x = 1; x <= n; x++)
    {
        fact *= x;
    }
    for (double y = 1; y <= r; y++)
    {
        foct *= y;
    }
    for (double z = 1; z <= n - r; z++)
    {
        fuct *= z;
    }

    // capture the value here to add to sum, we can also print that value then
    double value = (fact / (foct * fuct) * Math.Pow(p, r) * Math.Pow(1 - p, n - r));
    sum += value;
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}

Console.WriteLine("Sum: " + sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make it way shorter by using enumerable and linq I think.
By example you could replace the first loop (for the factorial) with :

```
var fact = Enumerable.Range(1, 12).Aggregate(1, (accumulator, nextValue) => accumulator * nextValue);
```

Small explanation :

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 12)
```

Will create an enumerable containing value from 1 to 12.

```
.Aggregate(1, (accumulator, nextValue) => accumulator * nextValue);
```

Will aggregate all values in your enumerable into a single one. The initial value (the seed) will be 1 and for each value in the enumerable the aggregation function will apply (current value (aka accumulator) * next value in the enumerable).

Once you understand the full line you can simply reuse it with different values of course.

Then you can create a method for it to reuse easily :

```
public static int Factorial(int value)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(1, value).Aggregate(1, (accumulator, nextValue) => accumulator * nextValue);
}
```